# Sumar registros de un DataTable

Tags: vb.net

Estimados muy buenas tardes, alguien puede ayudarme con el siguiente problema... necesito hacer una consulta sql en mi sistema en Visual Basic, la cual sume todos los montos registrados cuando el campo llamado "tipodocumento" sea factura o boleta, pero cuando el campo sea nota de credito, lo reste.

EL CODIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE

```
Dim varconexion = New SqlConnection(cadena)
    varconexion.Open()
    Dim DT As New DataTable

    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT numdocpago AS NUM, tipodocpago AS TIPO, fechadocpago AS FECHA, montodocpago AS MONTO, detalledocpago AS DETALLE, numordcomp AS ORDEN_COMPRA, numctactble AS CTA_CTBLE, rutprov AS RUT, digitoprov AS DIG, nomprov AS PROVEEDOR FROM docpago WHERE numdecpago = '" & tbxNumDecreto.Text & "' AND fechadecpago = '" & dtpFechaDecreto.Text & "' AND nomdepto = '" & cbxDepto.Text & "' ORDER BY numdocpago", varconexion)
    DA.Fill(DT)
    dgvVisualizaPago.DataSource = DT

    varconexion.Close()

    'SUMAR COLUMNA
    dgvVisualizaPago.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##,##0"
    Dim ddt As DataTable = DirectCast(dgvVisualizaPago.DataSource, DataTable)

    Dim sumMONTO As Object = ddt.Compute("SUM(MONTO)", Nothing) 'aqui quiero el codigo, actualmente solo entrega una suma, pero quiero hacer el filtro antes mencionado para restar si el tipodocpago es = "NOTA DE CREDITO"

    lblMontoTotal.Text = Nothing

    If sumMONTO Is DBNull.Value Then
        sumMONTO = "0"
    Else
        lblMontoTotal.Text = sumMONTO
        lblMontoTotal.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(lblMontoTotal.Text).ToString("N0")
    End If
```

Comment: Por favor agrega a tu pregunta el nombre y estructura de la tabla, con datos de ejemplo. También etiqueta tu pregunta con el motor de base de datos y su versión

Comment: ya lo edite, gracias!

Comment: Prueba a ver si te sirve SELECT sum(CASE WHEN tipodocumento='factura' OR tipdocumento='boleta' THEN montodocumento ELSE -montodocumento END) FROM tabla

Comment: @Francisco Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ok, lo que necesitas es que en tu `DataTable` se haga la operación, no estoy seguro si con `Compute` se pueda hacer ya que la condición que tienes no es trivial.

Lo que puedes hacer es sumar vía LINQ trasformado tu datatable a enumerable

Sería algo así

```
'Suma positivo
Dim cargoTotal = ddt .AsEnumerable().Where(Function(c) c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "factura"  Or c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "boleta").Sum(Function(c) c.Field(Of Integer)("MONTO"))

'Suma negativo
Dim abonoTotal = ddt .AsEnumerable().Where(Function(c) c.Field(Of String)("TIPO") = "credito").Sum(Function(c) c.Field(Of Integer)("MONTO"))
```

Y ya solo tendrías que restarlos para obtener la cantidad que quieres. Quiza haya una forma de hacerlo solo en un query, pero como hace mucho que no toco el VB.NET al menos te puede ayudar.

---

Primera respuesta

Puede usar algo como esto:

```
SELECT 

SUM(
  CASE WHEN tipodocumento = 'factura' OR tipodocumento = 'boleta' 
  THEN montodocumento -- aqui suma
  WHEN tipodocumento = 'credito' 
  THEN  montodocumento * -1 END --aqui resta (puede ser tambien -montodocumento )
)

FROM MITABLA
```

Aqui usamos un CASE con la condición que pides, si factura o boleta suma

Y quiza al final debas usar un `group by` por algun elemento

Comment: Me sale el siguiente mensaje en visual basic: Error de sintaxis en el argumento aggregate: Se esperaba una columna simple con un calificador 'Child'

Comment: @Francisco puedes agregar el codigo donde invocas el query en tu pregunta

Comment: ya lo agregue!!!!

Comment: @Francisco ya vi cual es tu problema checa la actualización de mi respuesta espero te funcione

Comment: me funciono a la perfección, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de realizar lo que necesitas por medio de una consulta seria algo asi:

```
SELECT (factura+boleta-credito) AS total

FROM

(SELECT 
      CASE WHEN tipodocumento = 'factura' THEN SUM(montodocumento) ELSE 0 END AS 
      factura,
      CASE WHEN tipodocumento = 'boleta' THEN SUM(montodocumento) ELSE 0 END AS 
      boleta, 
      CASE WHEN tipodocumento = 'nota de credito' THEN SUM(montodocumento) ELSE 0 END AS credito

FROM docspago 

GROUP BY tipodocumento)
```

Answer (score -1):

prueba esto en cuanto a visula basic
=SUMA(A2:A10) Suma

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: La pregunta no es sobre excel